# Power output calculation - am I correct?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am trying to estimate the electrical power a mechanical machine may generate - is my calculations/understanding correct (to a plus/minus 50% error)?

So, I have a mechanical machine whereby a shaft is pushed up (by what I'd rather not say) and is returned at the top of the stroke by a spring, then the process repeats. Similar to a piston in an ICE.

The 'force' (I'll explain shortly) is not linear along it's travel. It goes from 9.5Kg at 1mm from start, to 2Kg at 6mm. Averaging all my data points I get 4.3Kg over a distance of 5mm.

I understand force is measured in Newtons, so I can just multiple by 9.8?

This process repeats 50 times a second, or every 0.02 seconds.

So, if I connect this to a crankshaft and turn a generator,  I believe I will get 10.5 watts of electrical power, assuming no losses, and using my method of simply averaging the force along the travel,

I get 10.6W like so:

Power in watts = work in joules / time

Power in watts = 4.3Kg * 0.005 meters * 9.8 / 0.02 seconds

**Edit in response to Mike Jordan's answer.**

Unfortunately, I do not understand your answer. This is not my area so am just trying to get a proof of concept before getting the assistance I clearly need.

To try to answer your questions at the end, yes, I'm measuring the force with a load cell calibrated in Kgs.

*Since you have the spatial average not the temporal one (right?)* - I don't know, I guess the former? Are you saying to multiply the stroke (5mm) by what value? Is that wat I did? Is my answer then per stroke?

Answer (score 3):

Power is computed from the definition of work, so
$$
P(t) =\mathbf{F}(t)\cdot\mathbf{v}(t)
$$ Averaging over some time 0 to T.
$$
P_{avg} = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \mathbf{F}(t)\cdot\mathbf{v}(t)dt$$
Assuming your force and velocity are always parallel, we just get
$$
P_{avg} = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T F(t)v(t)dt
$$
We can rewrite this in terms of an integral over position (single stroke)
$$
P_{avg} = \frac{1}{T}\int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(x)dx
$$
Because $v dt = dx$. And this gives the spatial average force
so $$
P_{avg} = \frac{x_2-x_1}{T}F_{avg}
$$
Since you have the spatial average not the temporal one (right?), you can just multiply by stroke length to get the work done, then divide by the time per stroke to get the average power during one stroke.
Force is not measured in 'kg', but presumably your device is measuring effective mass, then yes multiply by $g\approx 9.8m s^{-2}$, so seem correct to me.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I added some extra info to the end of my questiion in response.